# Если я прекращу подписку Github станет ли мой репозиторий публичным?

Tags: github

Нужен репозиторий на 2-3 месяца, потом возможно будет перерыв (неясно сколько по времени) и потом опять начнем разработку
Если мы не будем платить за время перерыва, станет ли наш репозиторий в этот момент публичным?

Comment: Думаю вопрос не касается тематики сайта, думаю вам лучше обратится в поддержку пользователей  указаного ресурса (github)

Answer (score 3):

#### Не станет. Но вы тоже потеряете к нему доступ.

> When you downgrade your billing plan, your new plan takes effect on your next billing date. Make sure to back up your private repositories before your next billing date, or you won't be able to access them without upgrading to a paid plan again.
>
> — https://help.github.com/articles/downgrading-a-user-account-to-free/

> Переход на тариф ниже произойдёт, когда закончится расчётный период. Не забудьте снять резервные копии приватных репозиториев до окончания расчётного периода, или не сможете обращаться к ним, не перейдя вновь на платный тарифный план.